# How to remove files using grep and rm?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

```
grep -n magenta *| rm *
```

`grep: a.txt`: No such file or directory

`grep: b`: No such file or directory

Above command removes all files present in the directory except ., ..  .
It should remove only those files which contains the word "magenta"

Also, tried `grep magenta * -exec rm '{}' \;` but no luck.
Any idea?

Comment: A duplicate of many other questions.  The key part of the answer is usually `xargs`.  The bells and whistles vary.  The `-n` option is counter-productive; in fact, you probably want `-l` instead.

Comment: should notice that `-exec` is only the weird argument of `find`. `grep` doesn't have that shit :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `xargs`:

```
grep -l --null magenta ./* | xargs -0 rm
```

The purpose of xargs is to take input on stdin and place it on the command line of its argument.

What the options do:

- The `-l` option tells grep not to print the matching text and instead just print the names of the files that contain matching text.
- The `--null` option tells grep to separate the filenames with NUL characters.  This allows all manner of filenames to be handled safely.
- The `-0` option to xargs to treat its input as NUL-separated.

Comment: Note that the `-Z` option is non-standard — it is supported by GNU `grep`; it is not supported on Mac OS X for example.  Or, more precisely, on Mac OS X, the `-z` and `-Z` options mean 'decompress` and `--null` prints nulls after the file name.  But the answer has been updated to use `--null` anyway.  That is still not 'POSIX standard', but sometimes, the official standards take time to catch up with the real world.

Comment: typo "The -l option tells grep to produce only filenames without matching text" is true for capital 'l' -L, lowercase 'l' -l outputs the filename only, none of the match information. So your example is GOOD but the description of that option is BAD.

Comment: @rob  I read that sentence differently but I clearly see your point: answer rephrased to remove that ambiguity. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a safe way:](https://superuser.com/questions/585391/on-linux-how-can-i-find-all-files-that-contain-a-string-and-delete-them/585436#585436)

```
grep -lr magenta . | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

- `-l` prints file names of files matching the search pattern.
- `-r` performs a recursive search for the pattern `magenta` in the given directory `.`. 
  If this doesn't work, try `-R`.
  (i.e., as multiple names instead of one).
- `xargs -0` feeds the file names from `grep` to `rm -f`
- `--` is often forgotten but it is very important to mark the end of options and allow for removal of files whose names begin with `-`.

If you would like to see which files are about to be deleted, simply remove the `| xargs -0 rm -f --` part.

Comment: No; this is looking at file names; the question is looking at file contents.

Comment: See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779632/how-to-remove-files-using-grep-and-rm/31779697?noredirect=1#comment51489207_31779688) about `-Z` and portability (or lack thereof).  The `-I` option also suffers from being non-portable.

Comment: Thanks for this @JonathanLeffler. Will edit the answer